# Shift all "deadline" and "scheduled" ahead of 2w

Tags: org-mode

I am using spacemacs, but this question is emacs-related.

I have a long list of "deadlines" and "scheduled" in a .org file, and I would like to know how to shift all the dates at once of 14 days.

I can't understand properly what I find if I google this issue, or more probably I didn't understand properly how a .org file is written. Let's say for example that I have

```
** L9 : TASK XYZ
   SCHEDULED: <2017-11-29 Wed>

** L11 : TASK XYZ
   SCHEDULED: <2017-12-13 Wed>  

** L13 : TASK XYZ
   SCHEDULED: <2018-01-10 Wed>

** L15 : TASK XYZ
   SCHEDULED: <2018-01-24 Wed>

** L17 : TASK XYZ
   SCHEDULED: <2018-02-07 Wed>

** L19 : TASK XYZ
   SCHEDULED: <2018-02-21 Wed>

** L21 : TASK XYZ
   SCHEDULED: <2018-03-07 Wed>

** L23 : TASK XYZ
   SCHEDULED: <2018-03-21 Wed>
```

What shall I do to shift everything by 2 weeks?

Comment: If you use agenda views, they support bulk operations on marked entries. See [this blog post](http://pragmaticemacs.com/emacs/reschedule-multiple-items-in-org-agenda/) for a summary and [`(org) Agenda commands`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html) for a listing of commands (search for the "
bulk remote editing selected entries" heading). I don't know if the same key bindings are maintained under Spacemacs/Evil.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to do this interactively with the `multiple-cursors` package.

If what you show is all that is in the buffer or the buffer is narrowed to what you see place your cursor on one of the "SCHEDULED" headings and run `M-x mc/mark-all-like-this-dwim`.  This creates cursors for each SCHEDULED keyword.  Move the cursors forward to the day of the month position and press `C-u 14 <S-up>` or (`SPC u 14 <S-up>` in Spacemacs.  That's "Shift-Up" which is bound to `org-shiftup` which can adjust things like dates, priorities, etc.  The `C-u 24` is the universal prefix argument that instructs the command to repeat the value 24 times.  Answer yes to the mc prompt the first time you try it and Bob's your Uncle!

Comment: C-u brings me to the beginning of buffer... maybe this only works in emacs?

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Ah right.  In Spacemacs the universal prefix argument is `SPC u`.